# doctrine: fetching all objects which parent is in the list

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

assume I have two objects `article` and `comment`. What I would like to do is to fetch all comments, which article.id is IN (1,2,3,4). What is the best way to achieve it ? Am I forced to use JOIN? Right now I have something like this;

```
dql = "SELECT c FROM Comment c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.article a WHERE a.id IN :articles ORDER BY a.id ASC";
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameter("articles", array(1,2,3,4));
```

I haven't tested this query but I believe something like this should work, but it would be lovely to write something like c.article IN articles (without JOIN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work, AFAIK:

```sql
SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.article IN(:articles)
```

```php
$query->setParameter('articles', array(1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: yes, wrong syntax around ')' :) i guess the issue is that it changes :articles into "(1,2,3,4" instead of ("1","2","3","4"). I just used implode function, but i wanted to avoid it

Comment: I just double-checked, and that works. I think you forgot the parentheses in the DQL query: you need to use `IN (:articles)`, not `IN :articles`

Comment: and what you put in :articles ? just an array like $array = (1,2,3,4) ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I'm using 2.2; you should give it a try if you can!